# Send Intent to use default mail app in android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

Delphi XE5 (Android App).

Doing a small app and just want to get some feedback .

How can I send an intent to use a simple TEdit for Subject,
 and Tmemo for Message and send it to the default mail client on the end users phone.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the Share Sheet may can do this.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Invoking an intent? Identifying which intent to use? Some Delphi-specific aspect of one of those things? [Edit] to make your question more specific, please.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am looking at the share sheet to attach the text to . I thought we may have to wrap an intent to do it but the share sheet looks promising .

Comment: So, do you still need an answer to the question you asked here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ought to help the process. Pass in the values from the UI controls.

```
uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
...
procedure CreateEmail(const Recipient, Subject, Content: string);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  Recipients: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  Recipients := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  Recipients.Items[0] := StringToJString(Recipient);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, Recipients);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString(Content));
  //Intent.setType(StringToJString('plain/text'));
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('message/rfc822'));
  //SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
  SharedActivity.startActivity(TJIntent.JavaClass.createChooser(Intent,
    StrToJCharSequence('Which email app?')));
end;
```