# How send email Android with c++ builder?

Tags: android, c++, android-intent, c++builder

I have seen many examples in Delphi and not one a C ++ builder. I tried to recreate the code in C ++, but it flies only exception. How to use the Intent to С++?

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    callEmail("russia@gmail.com", "Application");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TForm1::callEmail(const String address, const String Subject){
  JIntent* intent;
  TJIntent* intentTwo;
  intent = intentTwo->Create();
  intent->setAction(intentTwo->JavaClass->ACTION_SEND);
  intent->setFlags(intentTwo->JavaClass->FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent->putExtra(intentTwo->JavaClass->EXTRA_EMAIL, StringToJString(address));
  intent->putExtra(intentTwo->JavaClass->EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
  intent->setType(StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'));
  SharedActivity()->startActivity(intent);
}
```

I thnik, maybe I think maybe something needs to change in androidmanifest or user-permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is crashing because you are not constructing the Intent object correctly.

`Create()` is a constructor in Delphi.  `intent := TJIntent.Create` in Delphi would be `intent = new TJIntent` in C++.

Also, Embarcadero uses interfaces for its iOS/Android bridge frameworks, so you should use the provided `DelphiInterface<T>` typedefs, such as `_di_JIntent` instead of `JIntent*` directly.

Also, `JavaClass` (and `OCClass` in iOS) is a static class property.  You do not need an object instance to access it, just the class type.

Also, C++ uses single-quotes for character literals and double-quotes for string literals, whereas Delphi uses single-quotes for both. `'vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'` in C++ is not a string literal, it is a multi-byte character literal instead, which is not what you want here.  Use double-quotes instead.

Also, `EXTRA_EMAIL` must be expressed as an array of strings.

Try something more like this:

```
void TForm1::callEmail(const String address, const String Subject)
{
    _di_JIntent intent;
    intent = new TJIntent; // or: intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init();
    intent->setAction(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_SEND);
    // or: intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_SEND);
    intent->setFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JString> *Recipients = new TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JString>(1);
    Recipients->Items[0] = StringToJString(address);
    intent->putExtra(TJIntent::JavaClass->EXTRA_EMAIL, Recipients);
    intent->putExtra(TJIntent::JavaClass->EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
    intent->setType(StringToJString(L"vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"));
    SharedActivity()->startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now, that said, you really should not be using `vnd.android.cursor.dir/email` as the intent's MIME type. Use `message/rfc822` instead, or even `plain/text`. But those do not limit the intent to just email clients, other apps might also support those types.  To send an email using only a true email client, use `ACTION_SENDTO` with a `mailto:` URI instead. For 1 recipient, you can put the address directly in the URI and not use `EXTRA_EMAIL` at all. For 2+ recipients, use a `mailto:` URI with no address in it and use `EXTRA_EMAIL` for the addresses. This is mentioned in the Android documentation:

[Common Intents | Email](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email)

For example:

```
void TForm1::callEmail(const String address, const String Subject)
{
    _di_JIntent intent;
    intent = new TJIntent; // or: intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init();
    intent->setAction(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent->setData(StrToJURI(L"mailto:" + address));
    // or: intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_SENDTO, StrToJURI(L"mailto:" + address));
    intent->setFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent->putExtra(TJIntent::JavaClass->EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
    intent->setType(StringToJString(L"message/rfc822"));
    SharedActivity()->startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank! It's work! Another small question, how to run a default email application?

Comment: Somehow EXTRA-MAIL is not passed

Comment: `EXTRA_EMAIL` must contain an array of strings, even if it only has 1 element. Use `TJavaObjectArray<String>` to create that array.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19344140/65863) for an example.

Comment: I do not know how to express my gratitude! Thanks!